# Implementing an SSO solution

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identity, openid-provider, openid-connect

I'm looking to replace our current SSO system based on openID 1, with an authentication and authorization solution that is more suiting modern needs.

One of the things i would like to avoid is having the end user redirected to the identity provider for various flows, such as login, reset password, etc.

Is there a secure solution that doesn't rely on redirects between the relying parties and the identity provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the point of federated web single signon is that you relay control of user authentication to a trusted 3rd-party, so by design you cannot do login and password resets from the Relying Party without redirecting to the Identity Provider. Any implementation that allows that would defeat the primary purpose of federated Web SSO that the RP should not know/need/manage the users credentials.

Comment: Can you call your identity provider using ajax and avoiding http redirect ?

Comment: no, as that also defeats the point: your AJAX code would need to consume and thus learn user credentials that are meant to be presented by the user to the OP only